# Wordpress, very slow loading of one of the subpage

Tags: wordpress, performance-testing

recently one of subpage on my website loads really slow, here's the link:
http://rankingmlm.com/rankingi/

I check on http://gtmetrix.com/ how the site is loaded and it tells, that server response is the most slowest thing, but another subpages load normally, pretty fast I think. I haven't made any changes recently.

Can someone check it?

Comment: All of your subpages load damn slow. Maybe the other websites were just cached for you?

Comment: Yeah, you right, I just tried on incognito mode and it is really damn slow, but which I mentioned in last post is the slowest, loads 3 or 4 times loger than the others. Do you have any idea why it happens?